# How can I change my application state using ui-router from inside an interceptor?

Tags: angularjs

My config file looks like this:

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', '$locationProvider', '$sceProvider', '$state', '$stateProvider', function (
             $httpProvider,   $locationProvider,   $sceProvider,   $state, $stateProvider) {

        $sceProvider.enabled(false);
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push(authInterceptor);

        var authentication = {
            name: 'authentication',
            url: '/authentication',
            views: {
                'root': {
                    templateUrl: function (stateParams) {
                        return '/Content/app/authentication/partials/home.html';
                    }
                }

            }
        };

        $stateProvider
            .state(authentication)
            .etc etc etc
```

Here's my Interceptor:

```
app.factory('authInterceptor', function ($q, $rootScope, $state) {

    function success(response) {
        return response;
    }

    function error(response) {

        if (response.status === 401) {
            $state.transitionTo('authentication')
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
        else {
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    }

    return function (promise) {
        return promise.then(success, error);
    }
})
```

The problem that I have is that when I run the application I am getting a message saying:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $state
```

Can someone give me some advice on how I could make the state change if I receive a 401 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you used the event system and `$rootScope`?

For example, in your interceptor:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('authenticationFailed');
```

And in some parent controller:

```
$rootScope.$on('authenticationFailed', function(event){
    // authentication failed, so transition or what ever
    $state.transitionTo('authentication');
});
```